# How can I get a screenshot of all the comments in an instagram post?

Tags: firefox

How can I get a screenshot of all the comments in an Instagram post with firefox?

Because of the scroll box I can get the screenshot of all the comments at once in a practical way :(

I was able to manage the web style with the "style editor" to deactivate the scroll box, but in newer versions of firefox, the style editor rules are together so I can't do that anymore.

I hope someone can give me please a solution.

Recap: So the goal is: take a screenshot of all the comments of an instagram post, not a screenshot of the full page [that's something different because of the scroll box].

Comment: A trivial idea which requires non-trivial care in execution: Multiple serial screenshots, then cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 1):

A screen capture utility known as [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) allows scrolling screen capture. As a test, I opened a tab for SE questions listing and activated the feature (print screen) after setting the parameters for scrolling capture.

When pressed, print-screen is followed by a "request" to confirm window, at which point the screen gets a bit of jitter. In a moment or two, the capture preview window feature appeared and showed a single image of substantial length and normal screen width.

> Scrolling Screen Capture
>
> Take a full-page, scrolling screenshot. Snagit's screen capture tool
>   makes it simple to grab vertical and horizontal scrolls, infinitely
>   scrolling webpages, long chat messages, and everything in between.

There may be other free capture software packages available with this feature, but of them I know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Fireshot add-on.  Open up all the comments first, you may need to scroll to the top.  Select "selection", Control_Click inside the comments frame. [FireShot: Full Web Page Screenshots (♥♥♥♥♥) – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/). (I have the pro version which now is expensive, you will need to test whether the free version does it, it probably will.)